# Problema con Http post Angularjs2

Tags: laravel, angularjs-2.0, typescript

he seguido el tutorial de formularios en la documentación de Angularjs2, pero no consigo enviarlo por el método post

He creado la clase como en el ejemplo

```
export class Hero {
   constructor(
     public id: number,
     public name: string,
     public power: string,
     public alterEgo?: string
   ) {  }
}
```

Luego la llamo de esta forma

```
    this.hero = new Hero(42, 'SkyDog',
                   'Fetch any object at any distance',
                   'Leslie Rollover');
```

Y mi metodo de guardar es

```
    save(hero){     
  this.http.post('mi-url', hero,
    { headers: this.headers }).map(response => response.json())
    .subscribe(
        data => console.log('data', JSON.stringify(data)),
        error => console.log(JSON.stringify(error)),
        () => console.log('Completed')
    );      
}
```

ahora bien, mi objeto en consola se muestra creado correctamente, pero en laravel estoy recibiendo un objeto vacio, la respuesta que me da es "[]", un objeto vacio

mientras que si cambio la linea y pongo

```
    this.http.post('mi-url', JSON.stringify(hero), etc etc);
```

obtengo esta respuesta en laravel

```
    {"id":42,"name":"SkyDog","power":"Fetch_any_object_at_any_distance","alterEgo":"Leslie_Rollover"}: ""
```

He intentado resolverlo pero creo que estoy dejando pasar algo por alto

en laravel solo estoy retornando el objeto de esta forma

```
    public function store(Request $request)
   { 
     if($request->ajax())
     {
      return $request->all();
     }             
   }
```

Comment: ¿Qué problema tienes con el objeto que recibes cuando conviertes el objeto con los valores del formulario (```hero```) en una cadena para enviarlo vía POST? Según comentas en Laravel recibes los valores del formulario.

Comment: hola, si, los recibo pero no puedo hacer nada con ellos, Laravel me responde con esto { " {\"id\":42,\"name\":\"SkyDog\"} " : " " }, es decir, un objeto vacio.

Comment: ¿Y si haces el proceso inverso de pasar la cadena a variable de PHP? Por ejemplo con json_decode ()? http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Según lo que estuve leyendo, parece ser que necesito enviarla en este formato "id=42&name=skydog", así si funciona, no se si es la versión que estoy usando de Angular, o todas son iguales.

Comment: Esa es la forma del estándar HTTP de enviar los datos (ya sea por POST o por GET) pero normalmente tanto en el cliente (Angular) como el servidor hay librerías que te evitan tener que hacerlo a mano. Creo que debes incluir información más clara y precisa de tu problema original. La sensación que me da es que estás tanteando varias formas de intentar solucionar tu problema que están añadiendo confusión. Por último, has probado lo que he comentado de decodificar el JSON que recibes? SI no te vale detalla claramente por qué esto no sirve.

Comment: Estaría bien que pusieras más codigo, como por ejemplo el valor de la variable `this.headers`

Comment: ¿Ya solucionaste el problema?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El método de Angular, *post* está definido como:

```
this.http.post(urlHaciaDondeEnviarLosDatos, datosAEnviar, cabecerasAdicionales)
```

Siendo:

- **urlHaciaDondeEnviarLosDatos** la ruta que escucha tu servidor para el post. Esto lo tienes ya resuelto.
- **datosAEnviar** es donde se encuentran tus dudas.

### ¿Por qué?

Porque tu frontEnd (*Angular*), está escrito en lenguaje *JavaScript*. Mientras que tu backEnd (*Laravel*), está escrito en lenguaje *PHP*.

Si quieres enviar un objeto *JavaScript* a *PHP*, no podrás hacerlo de manera directa ya que son diferentes lenguajes de programación. Por lo tanto, hacer:

```
this.http.post(..., hero, ...)
```

No tiene demasiado sentido, ya que tu variable *hero*, está referenciando un objeto *JavaScript*. Llegando a Laravel un objeto vacío (`[]`) que es el escenario que describes.

### Entonces, ¿Cómo enviar datos de un lenguaje a otro?

Fácilmente puedes enviar texto plano de un lenguaje a otro. Por lo tanto una solución es convertir tu objeto de *JavaScript* a **Texto**, luego enviar ese texto y recibirlo en Laravel. Por último, convertir ese Texto a un objeto de *PHP*.

En resumen:

1. Convertir *Objeto Javascript* a *Texto*.
2. Enviar desde JavaScript(Angular) ese Texto.
3. Recibir con PHP(Laravel) ese Texto.
4. Convertir *Texto* a *Objeto PHP*.

Pero *Texto* puede ser cualquier cosa. Lo bueno, es que se estandarizaron ciertos formatos de texto para el intercambio de datos. *XML* es uno de ellos, **JSON** es el más sencillo y popular (A su vez, este formato es un subconjunto de otro llamado *YAML*).

1. Para convertir en JavaScript un **Objeto a Texto**

Usas:

```
JSON.stringify(objeto);
```

Por lo tanto, cuando estás haciendo `JSON.stringify(hero)`, *JavaScript* está convirtiendo tu objeto *hero* a este texto:

```
{
  "id":42,
  "name":"SkyDog",
  "power":"Fetch_any_object_at_any_distance",
  "alterEgo":"Leslie_Rollover"
}
```

2. Luego Angular envía este texto a tu servidor.
3. Laravel recibe esto. Y cuando muestras el contenido, ves que es ese el texto que estás recibiendo. (*Aunque sin los espacios, claro*)

Pero, si te quedas ahí, te estaría faltando un paso:

4. Convertir ese texto a un objeto que pueda manejar PHP.

Esto lo consigues usando una función de *PHP* llamada `json_decode`. Entonces, para convertir ese texto en un *Objeto PHP*, podrías hacerlo así:

```
$hero = json_decode($request->getContent());
```

Guardando en la variable `$hero` tus datos. De forma que si muestras con `var_dump($hero);` obtendrás:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (4) { 
  ["id"]=> int(42) 
  ["name"]=> string(6) "SkyDog" 
  ["power"]=> string(32) "Fetch_any_object_at_any_distance" 
  ["alterEgo"]=> string(15) "Leslie_Rollover" 
}
```

Y podrás acceder a una propiedad en particular escribiendo, por ejemplo; `$hero->name` que con `var_dump` podrás ver: `string(6) "SkyDog"`

Si te parece más cómodo convertir ese texto a un *Array Asociativo* en vez de a un *Objeto*, puedes usar el segundo parámetro de *json_decode*:

```
$hero = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
```

Y ahora `var_dump($hero);` te confirmará que es un Array:

```
array(4) { 
  ["id"]=> int(42) 
  ["name"]=> string(6) "SkyDog" 
  ["power"]=> string(32) "Fetch_any_object_at_any_distance" 
  ["alterEgo"]=> string(15) "Leslie_Rollover" 
}
```

Y podrás acceder a alguna propiedad escribiendo `$hero['name'];`.

Otra forma, dependiendo tu versión de *Laravel* (*Creo que 5.2+*), cuentas con un método que encapsula a *json_decode*. El mismo es:

```
$request->json()->all();
```

Ahora, volviendo a los parámetros de *this.http.post* en *Angular*...

- **cabecerasAdicionales** te servirá para decirle a *Laravel* que el texto que estás enviando, está en formato *JSON*.

Esto lo consigues escribiendo:

```
this.http.post(
  ..., 
  ..., 
  {headers: new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})}
)
```

***Nota***: **Headers** se encuentra en `import { Headers } from '@angular/http';`

Answer (score 0):

Creo que deberías convertir el objeto `hero` a *JSON* y pasárselo como parámetro similar a como lo estás haciendo directamente con el objeto pero en *JSON*.

Generalmente yo hago esto:

```
save(hero:Hero): Observable<Boolean>{
    let _json = JSON.stringify({ hero: hero });
    let _params = "json="+_json;
    if(!environment.production && environment.depurar){
        console.log("Enviando el objeto hero para ser registrado en la base de datos");
        console.log(_params);
    }
    let _headers = new Headers({
        "Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this._autenticacionService.token
    });
    let _options = new RequestOptions({ headers: _headers });
    return this._http.post(
        environment.api_url+'/urlapifunction/hero', _params, {headers: _headers}
    ).map((response: Response) => {
            let data=this._autenticacionService.extractData(response);
            if(data.success&&data.message!=""){
                this._helper.notificationToast(data.message,"Exito");
            }else{
                if(data.success)
                    this._helper.notificationToast("Hero registrado","Exito");
            }
            if(data.success) return true;
                return false;
        }).catch(err=>this._autenticacionService.handleError(err));
}
```

En el componente el cual hago uso del servicio, lo implemento así:

```
this._herosService.save(this.model).subscribe(
    registrado => {
        // console.log(registrado);
        if(registrado){
            this._router.navigate(['/heros']);
        }
    }
);
```