# ¿Como enviar datos de un Formulario Ionic a framework Laravel 5.5?

Tags: ionic2

Que tal amigos tengo un error en una aplicacion que estoy realizando. Mi Front-End esta realizado con IONIC 2(Angular) y mi backend tengo en laravel 5.5. No me da errores al compilar pero cuando reviso los datos que se envian desde el formulario hacia el servidor sale que se ha enviado vacio como pueden ver en la sentencia:

"SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'nombre' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `usuarios` (`ci`, `nombre`, `apellido`, `telefono`, `ciudad`, `calle`, `postal`, `correo`, `usuario`, `password`, `foto`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (, , , , , , , , , , , 2017-10-26 21:05:53, 2017-10-26 21:05:53))

Controlador de backend en laravel:

public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //  Usuario::create(Request->all());
        // return "Dato guardado";

```
    $usuario=new Usuario;

    $usuario->ci=$request->input('ci');
    $usuario->nombre=$request->input('nombre');
    $usuario->apellido=$request->input('apellido');
    $usuario->telefono=$request->input('telefono');
    $usuario->ciudad=$request->input('ciudad');
    $usuario->calle=$request->input('calle');
    $usuario->postal=$request->input('postal');
    $usuario->correo=$request->input('correo');
    $usuario->usuario=$request->input('usuario');
    $usuario->password=$request->input('password');

    $usuario->foto=$request->input('foto');



    $usuario->save();

    ///decodificar el json recibido 
    $request->json()->all();
```

he realizado los cambios respectivos basado en :[Problema con Http post Angularjs2](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/56394/problema-con-http-post-angularjs2/112655#112655)

Agradezco su ayuda